# hibernate parameter with that name [<name>] did not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, entitymanager

I am running the following code.

UserService.java

```
String alias = "u";
String select = "SELECT u.email";
String where = "u.userId = :id";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("id", userId);

List<User> users = db.findRecords(User.class, alias, select, where, params);
```

DB.java

```
public <T> List<T> findRecords(Class<T> entityClass, String entityAlias, String select, String where, Map<String, Object> params) {
    String sql = select + " FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " " + entityAlias;

    if (where != null) {
        sql = sql + " WHERE " + where;
    }

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    System.out.println(sql);
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + ", value: " + entry.getValue());
            query.setParameter((String) entry.getKey(), (Long) entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I am getting the following error log.

```
SELECT u.email FROM com.catalog.user.User u WHERE u.userId = :id
key: id, value: 28636907

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [id] did not exist
```

If the parameter is getting printed in the console then what is causing the illegal arguments exception to come up?

Please help!

Comment: Is your class `clues.catalog.user.User` is declared as entity?

Comment: Yes.

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cscart_users")
public class User {

 @Column(name = "user_id")
 public Long userId;

Comment: maybe something is going wrong with the string  concatenation since he says he can't find the :id parameter in the query...
can you try to do the create query with the correct string inside?
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u.email FROM clues.catalog.user.User u WHERE u.userId = :id");

Comment: Having the full stack trace might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) check that it is not a typo in the parameter name `:id`. It's case sensitive.

2) try to execute  query without parameters. It might be a problem in the entity mapping.

3) try to set parameter directly in the query without `HashMap`.

Comment: Point 2 is what was wrong. Some other entities did not have an identifier specified. Once I removed those entities it started working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is caused by the way you are getting the params from the `Map`, with the `Map.entrySet()` method the iterated values are only available within the iteration and will be undefined outside of it, that's why the param is correctly printed during the loop and doesn't exist in the query.

If you take a look at the [**Map.entry** documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) it says:

> These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the
>   iteration;

I suggest that you change the way you store and use the parameters , you can simply use a `List<Object>` to store the parameters or just pass the `id` param directly in the method call:

```
public <T> List<T> findRecords(Class<T> entityClass, String entityAlias, String select, String where, Long id){
```

Then directly append this value in the query:

```
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

Comment: I tried storing the key and value in variables but that didn't work either. And I can't add the id parameter in the function since it's a common function for all types of queries.